# Disable Microsoft Office auto update pop-up.

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, updates

When a new user runs an Office application on a new machine a popup appears asking if they want important updates. It then requires admin rights to apply the selected changes.

If the user is unaccompanied by an admin at this time they do not have the rights to properly satisfy the pop-up. How can I stop this popup? I have already set the update configuration while logged in and admin, I have clicked the box allowing any user to update the machine too.

Comment: The simplest way would be to install the updates on the machine before the user logs into it.

Answer (score 1):

This is done either via the Office Customization Tool or via Group Policy. OCT would be used to customize the installation, while the Group Policy will allow you to make changes if Office is already installed.

[source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/odsupport/archive/2012/11/13/how-to-manage-the-opt_2d00_in-or-first-things-first-prompt-when-microsoft-office-2013-applications-are-first-launched.aspx)

[image]

[image]